# Or condition in single Regex by last word not working python

Tags: python, regex

I am converting pdf bank statements into a text file and reading text file line by line and converting transactions into JSON formate using regex. Now transaction in the text some transactions having amount in the same line and some line having an amount in a different line. Want to write a single regex which can differentiate there two lines. Input string are given below which I get one by one.

```
15/08/2019       UPI/922722731244/PAYMENT

01/08/2019       MAB CHARGES FOR JUN19                         4.94
```

Regular expression tried is

```
\s*(?P<'+DATE_STR+'>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?P<'+DESCRIPTION_STR+'>[\s\S\d\D\w\W]*)\s(?P<'+AMOUNT_STR+'>([\d.-]+))
```

I expect the output with AMOUNT_STR to be in or condition and the result should be like.

I want a single regex which applied on a first statement give the output as
 DATE_STR = '15/08/2019 ' DESCRIPTION_STR = 'UPI/922722731244/PAYMENT' (for first string)
and when applied on a second statement give the output as

DATE_STR = '01/08/2019' DESCRIPTION_STR = 'MAB CHARGES FOR JUN19' AMOUNT_STR= '4.94'

Comment: what is your input string

Comment: first string: 15/08/2019       UPI/922722731244/PAYMENT

Comment: second string: 01/08/2019       MAB CHARGES FOR JUN19                         4.94

Comment: 4.94 should be in AMOUNT_STR

Comment: You want to match *both* lines and have a single match with `AMOUNT_STR = 4.94`?

Comment: I want a single regex which applied on a first statement give the output as DATE_STR = '15/08/2019 ' DESCRIPTION_STR = 'UPI/922722731244/PAYMENT' (for first string)  and when applied on a second statement give the output as DATE_STR = '01/08/2019' DESCRIPTION_STR = 'MAB CHARGES FOR JUN19' AMOUNT_STR= '4.94'

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution. In regex, AMOUNT_STR regex in condition to check the number at last with "." (dot) as the amount can contain "," (comma) so the regex I am using is

\s*(?P<' + DATE_STR + '>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})\s(?P<' + DESCRIPTION_STR + '>(.*?)(?=\d+\,*\d*.\d+|$))(?P<' + AMOUNT_STR + '>\d+\,*\d*.\d+)*